# 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException'

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, outlook

I was trying to retrieve my outlook contacts in c#.net Application.
But While creating an object of outlook application, I am getting the error

```
 "AnswerWizard = '((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ApplicationClass.(outlookObj)).AnswerWizard' threw an exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException'"
```

I tried to register the dll using revsvr32 "DLL Path", but I am getting the error of Module loaded but DLLRegisterServer not found.

This is the code that I have written :

```
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ds.Tables.Add("Contacts");
        ds.Tables[0].Columns.Add("Email ID");
        ds.Tables[0].Columns.Add("FirstName");
        ds.Tables[0].Columns.Add("LastName");

        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Items OutlookItems;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application outlookObj;
        MAPIFolder Folder_Contacts;

        outlookObj = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
        Folder_Contacts =(MAPIFolder)outlookObj.Session.GetDefaultFolder  (OlDefaultFolders.olFolderContacts);
        OutlookItems = Folder_Contacts.Items;

        for (int i = 0; i < OutlookItems.Count; i++)
        {
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ContactItem contact =(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ContactItem)OutlookItems[i + 1];
            DataRow dr = ds.Tables[0].NewRow();
            dr[0] = contact.Email1Address;
            dr[1] = contact.FirstName;
            dr[2] = contact.LastName;

            ds.Tables[0].Rows.Add(dr);
            if (i == 10)
                break;
        }
        dgvContacts.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        return ds;
```

And I am getting the count as zero.

Comment: This is a very general exception, you should post the code that it's getting thrown from

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Application.AnswerWizard ever worked in Outlook. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Please have a look at the code.
My aim is to develop an application that would allow the user to search for the structure of DR's for a person taking the data from outlook.

Comment: But exactly does it have to do with AnswerWizard? It is never even referenced in your code above.

Comment: This is the exception that is generated.When I brought cursor over the outlook object during the debuging time, I got this error.

Comment: Ok, so you get an error when VS IDE evaluates that property. Why does it matter if you do not use it in your code? Does your code function properly?

Comment: No the code written above is not working properly coz of the exception thrown. Could you suggest me any other solution for the same.

Comment: Which line of your code above raises the exception?

Comment: the line of code is "outlookObj = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();"

Comment: And what is the exact error? Again, what does it have to do with AnswerWizard if it is not even used in your code?